# Software for editing JPEG files directly? [i.e. block manipulation]

Tags: image-processing, file-format

In the case where a JPEG file must be edited, but without leaving the file "apparently" edited (i.e. leaving all metadata, spec-/format-ambiguities, DCT tables, etc., byte-identical to the original), **do any tools currently exist** for packing/unpacking raw sectors without modifying [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) bytes than *strictly* necessary (relative to the original file)?

**In particular, it's my understanding that the run-length coding used for compression will render a hex editor infeasible for this task** — if it weren't for that, that'd be *the* tool for this job. And no conventional image editor will even approximately minimize e.g. the Hamming distance between the original and re-saved file, which is a pretty-accurate proxy for what I'm requesting here.

---

I'm aware that there are [other forensic considerations](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Ejh2700/Detecting%20Doctored%20JPEG%20Images%20Via%20DCT%20Coefficient%20Analysis%20.pdf), in addition to mere visual "plausibility" of the edits, both *out-of-scope of this question*. The scope of this question is specifically about editing the file without leaving forensically noticeable changes to its structure.

Comment: Afaik JPEG has no RLE, it diagonally fourier transforms the 8x8 chunks of the image and the gzips the stream. But I am not very sure. Hopefully you get a detailed answer.

Comment: I'll share 2 incredibly comprehensive+authoritative reference documents: [ITU T.81](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf), [ECMA TR/98](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-TR/ECMA%20TR-098.pdf) it took me more than 10 minutes to find them, so I suppose a signal-boost on them is in order